# Any recommendations for a reference a PaaS that supports jboss

Tags: jboss, paas

I'm evaluating `PaaS` alternatives. One of my requirements is to support `JBoss`. Any suggestions, in addition to `OpenShift`, preferably including a simple but technically competent installation description.

Thanks in advance!
Rodrigo

Comment: Can you tell me a little more about what you are trying to do? Is it personal or business related? Do you want to host on your own hardware or use someone else's infrastructure? Are there budget concerns?

Comment: Sure. This is a skunkworks project to build a prototype of a service including a sophisticated UI, middle of the road JAVA, and heavy duty database. We decided to start it using the service's targeted production tech stack which includes JBoss.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to set up a PaaS which supports JBoss, [Cloudify](http://www.cloudifysource.org), the open-source PaaS stack, has a JBoss Recipe: https://github.com/CloudifySource/cloudify-recipes/tree/master/services/jboss

Disclaimer: I am one of the developers of Cloudify.

Answer (score 0):

OpenShift (from Red Hat - the JBoss people) supports EAP6.1, AS7, about to release wildfly, and all your DB right there on the platform.

Caveat - I work as an evangelist for OpenShift

Comment: @TheSteveO this used to be an option, until they cut the free extra quota. This is paid only from 31 January 2014, for 20$/month at least

Comment: No the free tier is completely there [I work there]. You still get 3 gears for free with each gear being 512 megs of ram and 1 gig of disk space. If you want more resources THEN you have to pay

Comment: @Eugene pay attention to some announcements we will have coming soon.